# I am trying to read a file in a specific way but for some reason it returns random white spaces

Tags: java

Basically what i am trying to do is read a file that contains some questions. The file is organized like this:

```
//The category of the question
Questions
//The question
Possible Answer
//Answer #1
//Answer#2
//Answer#3
//Answer#4
Right answer
//The right answer
Image
//The image path if it exists
```

This is for only one question. There are multiple questions like this.

```
private boolean readQuestion() {
    try {
        String line = this.reader.readLine();

        if (line == null) {
            return false;
        }

        String category = "";
        String question = "";
        String[] possibleAnswers = {
            "",
            "",
            "",
            ""
        };
        String rightAnswer = "";
        String image = "";

        boolean imageQuestion = false;
        if (line.compareTo("Category") == 0) {} else {
            //read the category
            category = this.reader.readLine();
        }

        if (line.compareTo("Question") == 0) {
            //read the question (String question = ....)
            question = this.reader.readLine();
        }

        line = this.reader.readLine();

        if (line.compareTo("Possible answers") == 0) {
            //read four lines with the possible answers(String [] possibleAnswers = ...)
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                possibleAnswers[i] = this.reader.readLine();
            }
        }

        line = this.reader.readLine();

        if (line.compareTo("Right answer") == 0) {
            //read the right answer(String rightAnswer = ...)
            rightAnswer = this.reader.readLine();
        }

        line = this.reader.readLine();

        if (line.compareTo("Image") == 0) {
            //read the image name
            image = this.reader.readLine();
            imageQuestion = true;
        }

        BaseQuestion question1 = new BaseQuestion(question, possibleAnswers, rightAnswer, category);
        if (imageQuestion) {
            ImageQuestion imageQuestion_1 = new ImageQuestion(question1, image);
            this.questions.add(imageQuestion_1);
        } else {
            this.questions.add(question1);
        }

        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}

private void readFile() {
    while (this.readQuestion());
}
```

i have made the readQuestion boolean so that it returns if there is another question following. The reader is also a BufferedReader object. The BaseQuestion is a class that has a category, a question, 4 possible answers and a right answer. The imageQuestion has all the attributes of the BaseQuestion but also an imagePath.

Comment: Is that the exact file format, including the leading "//" characters?

Comment: no the "//" are to show the content it should have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have a NullPointerException (during 3rd iteration of you loop) on your if stmt. because line = null

```
 line = this.reader.readLine();

            if (line.compareTo("Image") == 0)
```

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.compareTo(String)" because "line" is null

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Demo d = new Demo();
        d.readFile();

        System.out.println(d.questions.size());
        for (Question q : d.questions) {
            System.out.println(q.toString());
```

where Question is just a dummy interface

```
interface Question {}

class BaseQuestion implements Question { ... }
```

this is the output I'm able to get from your class:

> 2
> BaseQuestion{question='', rightAnswer='', category='', possibleAnswers=[null, null, null, null]}
> BaseQuestion{question='', rightAnswer='', category='//Answer #1', possibleAnswers=[null, null, null, null]}

to see output presented above add these methods to your BaseQuestion and ImageQuestion classes:

```
@Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ImageQuestion{" +
                    "image='" + image + '\'' +
                    ", question1=" + question1 +
                    '}';
        }
```

and

```
@Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BaseQuestion{" +
                    "question='" + question + '\'' +
                    ", rightAnswer='" + rightAnswer + '\'' +
                    ", category='" + category + '\'' +
                    ", possibleAnswers=" + Arrays.toString(possibleAnswers) +
                    '}';
        }
```

You are reading here same line twice:

```
        if (line.compareTo("Category") == 0) {} else {
            //read the category
            category = this.reader.readLine();
        }

        if (line.compareTo("Question") == 0) {
            //read the question (String question = ....)
            question = this.reader.readLine();
        }
```

there's a missing readLine() between Category and Questions that's why the current line doesn't match your desired input

```
        if (line.compareTo("Category") == 0) {} else {
            //read the category
            category = this.reader.readLine();
        }

line = this.reader.readLine();

        if (line.compareTo("Question") == 0) {
            //read the question (String question = ....)
            question = this.reader.readLine();
        }
```

... and what's the purpose of this piece of code? are you sure it works as expected?

```
if (line.compareTo("Category") == 0) {} else {
            //read the category
            category = this.reader.readLine();
        }
```

Comment: this may also help you a bit [NullPointerException and BufferedReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29035681/nullpointerexception-and-bufferedreader)

Comment: I am getting the same output but at least the first question should show correctly. I don't exactly understand why i have done wrong.

Comment: @grigoriot I updated my answer - I hope it will be more clear now

Comment: so i updated the code and even added some checks to see whether line!=null but the outcome isn't the desired one. I also reorganized the file such as that after the right answer there will always be an Image. Although in the questions that don't have an image it just says 'No image'

Comment: Honestly i feel so stupid... that was the problem. the `category = this.reader.readLine()` should be in the if stmt not in the else block. Thank you for finding it. That's what happens when you attempt to code withouth sleeping.